# Git commit and push

Tags: git

I'm not totaly sure how `git commit` and `git push` works.

Let's say i `add` and `commit` something, then I make some changes in the same branch. Then I `push`.

Do I push only committed changes, or I push the branch at its current state?

I'm 95% positive that I only push committed changes, but I want to be sure. I don't want to mess something up by pushing uncommitted changes that I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only push what you have committed.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can push only commited changes. Nothing will be pushed without commit.